# Combine 2 different mySql result into one table

Tags: mysql

I like to combine two different mysql results into one table

first sql is

```
select     sum(cnt)             
from  xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v
```

and result will be

```
sum(cnt)
---------
67
```

second sql is

```
select sum(cnt)             
from xx_dept_emp_cnt_v          
where org_cb_id in (select cb_id from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v)
```

result will be

```
sum(cnt)
---------
62
```

how to write sql that will give me the result?

```
sum(cnt)        sum(cnt)
---------       ---------
67              62
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the two subqueries in the `select`.  I prefer to put them in the `from` clause and use `cross join`:

```
select cnt1, cnt2
from (select sum(cnt) as cnt1           
      from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v  
     ) h cross join
     (select sum(cnt) as cnt1           
      from xx_dept_emp_cnt_v          
      where org_cb_id in (select cb_id from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v) 
     ) d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(cnt), (select sum(s.cnt) from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v s where s.org_cb_id in (select x.cb_id from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v x) ) from xx_dept_hardware_cnt_v
```

You can use subqueries in select.